# f# query with equations

Tags: f#, sum, equations

I am working on some code where I need to use an f# query to sum a list.

For anyone who is working on f# basics, here's a handy link: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/fsharp/

So far, I have code that prints a statement for a sum of the square of 5 numbers.

So far, this correctly displays 3000 as the sum of the squares of each list. 'numbers' will be used for the query.

```
let square x = x * x
let numbers = [10.0; 20.0; 30.0; 40.0]

let sumOfSquare2 =
   [10.0; 20.0; 30.0; 40.0] 
   |> List.map square 
   |> List.sum 

printfn "Sum of square: %A" (sumOfSquare2)

let sumOfSquare = 
    List.sum ( List.map square [10.0; 20.0; 30.0; 40.0] )

printfn "Sum of square: %A" (sumOfSquare)
```

At the moment, I'm a little stuck on how to correctly use the 'square' function after the query.

```
// A query expression.

let query1 =
    query {
        for number in numbers do
            select (number)           
    }
   |> square query   


printfn "Query sum of squares: %A" (query1)
```

So how do I correctly present this? 'query' itself works (when using printfn on query) but when trying to pipeline the square function to query, it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

It will be basically the same code you used with the `list`, but since the query returns a `seq` use `Seq.map` instead of `List.map`:

```
// A query expression.
let query1 =
    query {
        for number in numbers do
            select (number)           
    }
   |> Seq.map square    


printfn "Query sum of squares: %A" (query1)
```

Note that your query does not transform anything, but I think you did like this as an example.

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much. This worked nicely. Just wondering how I would then add the values of query1 (since this print statement returns each of the list values squared). Would this need to be pipelined in the query1 expression?

Comment: @MichaelPotts that should be, again, the same as your initial example, just replace the list functions for the seq functions and it will work i.e. instead of ``List.sum`` use ``Seq.sum`` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly note that, the query returns a sequence which you can iterate and then do your operation

Ex:

```
// Print results of a query
query1
|> Seq.map (fun customer -> printfn "Company: %s Contact: %s" customer.CompanyName customer.ContactName)
```

You can use it like:

```
query1 |> Seq.map (fun e -> square(e)) |> Seq.sum
```

Full Source Code

```
open System

// your code goes here
let square x = x * x
let numbers = [10.0; 20.0; 30.0; 40.0]

let query1 =
    query {
        for number in numbers do
            select (number)           
    } |> Seq.map square |> Seq.sum

Console.WriteLine(sprintf "%A" query1);
```

[Try it](http://ideone.com/mgu6jM)

To learn more about the query, please go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions

Comment: let query1 |> Seq.iter (fun e -> square(e)) |> Seq.sum results in a compilation error. I don't really know how to apply this to my own issue. 
I have read the article you linked. It does not fix the issue I am having which is applying my squared function to the result of query.

Comment: Here's how I have understood your solution. This results in a compilation error. 
let query1 =
   query {
     for number in numbers do
          select (number)     
        } 
  |> Seq.iter (fun e -> square(query)) |> Seq.sum

Comment: If you look at the function signature of `Seq.iter`, you will see that it returns unit, hence it's generally used for its side-effect (e.g. printing to screen). Indeed you want `Seq.map` and then `Seq.sum`. Queries return seq, which are lazy, so if you want to force it the evaluation just pipe it to Array: `|> Seq.toList`

Comment: sorry, that should be a map instead of iter... fixed it

Answer (score 1):

F# supports summing within the query, so you can just do this to get the sum of the squares:

```
query {
    for num in numbers do
    sumBy (square num)
}
```